# Custom Post Type showing even when taxonomy is blank

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I am using **`Custom Post Type`** to get its contents by using **`Custom Taxonomy`** in different pages.

However, the contents are being displayed even if the post type has no taxonomy.

P.S. I am using **ACV** as well to get the fields of Taxonomy

**Here's the code:**

```
<?php if( get_field('review_category_name') ):
    $taxonomy_slug = get_field('review_category_name');  //Advanced Custom Field here
 endif; ?>
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'reviews','tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'reviews_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $taxonomy_slug,
    ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<div class="">
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Am I missing anything here?**

**`$taxonomy_slug`** is a variable to get the custom post type slug.

Comment: did you check slug value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything in the `get_field('review_category_name')` if check:

```
<?php if( get_field('review_category_name') ): ?>
<?php
    $taxonomy_slug = get_field('review_category_name');  //Advanced Custom Field here
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'reviews','tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'reviews_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $taxonomy_slug,
    ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="">
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

PS your example was missing the `endwhile`